# How to disable a usb device on boot?

Tags: linux, usb, fingerprint

My laptop has a fingerprint sensor which is broken.  Boot up proceess become very slow because linux failed to initialize the device and I can not shutdown the system properly.

**Here is the system log:**

```
[  192.999972] usb 1-5: new full-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[  193.340336] usb 1-5: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  193.790026] usb 1-5: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  194.060313] usb 1-5: new full-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[  194.390485] usb 1-5: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  194.840106] usb 1-5: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  194.959997] usb usb1-port5: attempt power cycle
[  195.669912] usb 1-5: new full-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[  200.720430] usb 1-5: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  205.919985] usb 1-5: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  206.189888] usb 1-5: new full-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[  211.279940] usb 1-5: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  216.480076] usb 1-5: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  216.599967] usb usb1-port5: unable to enumerate USB device
```

**Questions:**
1. How can I disable this device?

Comment: What do you mean by 'isolate', don't you mean disable? Can't this be disabled in the bios?

Comment: Yes, I mean disable this device on a specific usb port.  There is no such option to disable single usb port in dell's UEFI.

Comment: Maybe you could try to open the laptop and unplug the finger print reader from the main board? Probably would be the fastest way to do it. But maybe very messy. Up to you.

Comment: Within the BIOS it wouldn't be listed as a USB port but rather as what it is, a fingerprint sensor or a biometric sensor.

Comment: @Seth Dell doesn't provide such option.